# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS starts with a welcome screen on every restart

Tags: boot, login, users

For some reason on every restart Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS displays a welcome screen and i need to create a new user on every restart. Existing user are not displayed.

I was using 20.04 and I simply restarted the laptop after completing my work. No update was installed by me I think there could have been an background 20.04.02 update. Post the issue, updated ubuntu with patches hoping it will fix the issue, but the result is the same.

There was something strange in the last session i could not do basic  mv with sudo to /usr/local/bin and after few attempts i could. This never happened before. Was following https://book.kubebuilder.io/quick-start.html and installing kubebuilder. sudo did act funny.

Data related to the existing users is present.

How do i use my existing logins? SOS request please help.

Thanks Prashant

Comment: Most users who encounter this issue did not follow the installation instructions. or used some wacky custom installer, or chose the OEM install, or simply failed to remove the install media after it was complete.

Comment: I did not do any update simply restarted after i completed my work, that is what puzzles me. I was already on 20.04

Comment: See, that's important information that needs to be up in your question instead of buried in a comment.